# Send php variable to a class and run mysql query with Smarty

Tags: php, smarty

I would like to send a php variable to a class that runs a mysql query. It is a typical search via html form. I have to use Smarty.

How can I pass the variable "$minta" to the sql query and how to get the result array back to the php to display?

The Smarty tpl file is OK (lista_keres.tpl with the ingatlank variable).

Thank you in advance.

Tuwanbi

The php:

```
if (isset($_POST['keresoszo'])){

  include_once "classes/ingatlan.class.php";
  include_once "classes/main.class.php";
  include_once "classes/felhasznalo.class.php";

  $ingatlan = new Ingatlan();
  $felhasznalo = new Felhasznalo();
  $minta = $_POST['keresoszo'];

  $kereses = new Main();
  $kereses->getKeresIngatlan($minta);

        $smarty->assign("kapcsolattartok", $ingatlan->getKapcsolattartok());
        $smarty->assign("ingatlank", $main->getKeresIngatlan());
        $smarty->assign("include_file", lista_keres);

 echo $minta;
```

}

The class:

```
<?php

class Main{
private $keresoszo;
...
public function getKeresIngatlan($minta){

    $this->keresoszo=$minta;

    $ret = array();
    $sql="SELECT id FROM table WHERE id LIKE '% ".$keresoszo." %'";
    $ret = $this->db->GetArray($sql);
    return $ret;
}

}
?>
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: The Smarty template is not loading, I get only white page.

Comment: I don't see any $smarty->render() or such calls. Is any of those somewhere else in the code?

Answer (score 0):

Declaring `private $keresoszo;`  it becomes the class object and can be accessible by 
`$this->keresoszo` in you sql query you have assigned the value to this object but haven't used it

```
<?php

class Main{
private $keresoszo;
...
public function getKeresIngatlan($minta){

    $this->keresoszo=$minta;

    $ret = array();
    $sql="SELECT id FROM table WHERE id LIKE '% ".$this->keresoszo." %'";
    $ret = $this->db->GetArray($sql);
    return $ret;
}

}
?>
```

Here is what how you can get back the results

```
  $kereses = new Main();
  $results_set=$kereses->getKeresIngatlan($minta);
  var_dump($results_set);// for testing only 
        $smarty->assign("my_results_set", $results_set);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.
I have modified the php and the class but something is wrong, it does nothing, the template file is not loaded either.

If I comment the line
**$results_set=$kereses->getKeresIngatlan($minta);**
the template is loaded (without the results).